# Why won't my .net application accept the SQL Query via user input?

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, mariadb

I'm currently writing a quick .net program that will allow users to query a Database

I've got it working to a point where it'll run SELECT statements that are hardcoded but when I get the "sql" variable to look at the contents in a text box (user input) it chucks up an error. This happens even when I copy and paste a SQL Query that works hardcoded into the user text box

This is my code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class form_queueDepth

Public dbconn As New MySqlConnection
Public sql As String
Public dbread As MySqlDataReader
Public dbcomm As MySqlCommand

Private Sub form_queueDepth_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dbconn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=10.232.7.41;user id=Alex;password=abc;database=alexvb")

    Try
        dbconn.Open()
        MsgBox("Succeed")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Unable to connect: " & ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub button_ExecuteQuery_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button_ExecuteQuery.Click
    sql = "SELECT * FROM depth_store WHERE ID < '10';"
    dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
    MsgBox(sql)
    Try
        dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
        While dbread.Read
            listBox_QueryResults.Items.Add(dbread("Queue_Manager").ToString() & " | " & dbread("Queue").ToString() & " | " & dbread("DTime").ToString() & " " & dbread("QueueDepth").ToString())
        End While
        MsgBox("Success")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

SO the above code will work but the moment i change "sql = "SELECT * FROM depth_store WHERE ID < '10';" to "sql = (textBox_UserQuery).ToString"  and then copy & paste the query It chucks up an error stating:

http://i66.tinypic.com/2pqnxmo.png

Any suggestions/help would be much appreciated - Let me know if any you require any other information

Comment: textBox_UserQuery is probably the name of an instance of a TextBox. If you want to use its content you need the property Text. _sql = textBox_UserQuery.Text_

Comment: @Steve textbox_UserQuery is the name of the textbox - I made it pick up on the Text Property and it's worked perfect! Thanks a lot, that's had me going around in circles for a few hours now! :)

Comment: SQL injection attacked much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**textBox_UserQuery** is the name of an instance of a TextBox.
The ToString() method returns the name of the class

IE: *System.Windows.Forms.TextBox*.

If you want to use the content of a TextBox you need the property Text.

```
sql = textBox_UserQuery.Text
```

Said that, I hope that this 'program' is only for your internal use. If not you are giving away the capability to destroy an entire database. (DELETE FROM .....)

Comment: As i mentioned above, that solved my issue thanks! Program is only for internal use, I guess the ability to "delete" can also be managed via the account that the program is using on the database as if it has insufficient rights it wouldn't be able to execute it (i'd hope!)